# Remote access a linux system that has internet via android wifi tethering

Tags: internet, android, remote-access, tethering

I have a notebook with a linux system. This notebook is online through an android phone via wifi tethering. 
Now on my windows system I want to administrator that notebook over the internet. What would be a secure way to do this? In short:

Windows-> Internet -> android phone w/ hotspot -> notebook connected to phone

I could use a linux in a vm if that would make things easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you are fine with doing administration via command line, install [putty](http://www.putty.org/) on your Windows computer, and use it as an [ssh client](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell) for the Linux computer. That is a secure and encrypted connection, and it doesn't really matter how the Linux computer gets onto the internet. No need to use a linux vm.